# std::stable_sort vs std::sort

Tags: c++, string, sorting, stl, stable-sort

https://leetcode.com/problems/largest-number/

When I was solving the above problem, I came across the case where `std::sort()` was giving me a runtime error, but replacing it with `std::stable_sort()` then there was no runtime error. Why?

**Line is highlighted with the arrow sign on right**

Code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    string reverse(string str)
    {
        int n=str.length();
        for(int i=0;i<n/2;i++)
        {
            swap(str[i],str[n-i-1]);
        }
        return str;
    }

    static bool comp(string s1,string s2)
    {
        int min_val=min(s1.length(),s2.length());
        int i=0;
        bool flag=false;
        for(;i<min_val;i++)
        {
            if((s1[i]-'0')==(s2[i]-'0'))
            {
                flag=true;
                continue;
            }

            return (s1[i]-'0')>(s2[i]-'0');
        }

        if(flag==true && s1.length()==s2.length())
        {
            return s1==s2;
        }

        string s1_temp=s1;
        string s2_temp=s2;
        s1_temp+=s2;
        s2_temp+=s1;

        return s1_temp>s2_temp;
    }

    string largestNumber(vector<int>& nums)
    {
        string str="";
        vector<string> inp;

        for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++)
        {
            string temp="";
            long long int num=nums[i];
            if(num!=0)
            {
                while(num!=0)
                {
                    temp+=((num%10)+'0');
                    num/=10;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                temp+=(num+'0');
            }

            inp.push_back(reverse(temp));
        }

        stable_sort(inp.begin(),inp.end(),comp); // <-- This Line

        string res="";

        for(int i=0;i<inp.size();i++)
        {
            res+=inp[i];
        }
        cout<<"yes"<<endl;
        if(res[0]=='0')
        {
            return "0";
        }

        return res;
    }
};
```

TestCase:

> [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

Can anybody give me the reason why this happened?

Comment: What was the error with regular sort?

Comment: Why do you need a custom compare function? Can you not leave `comp` away entirely?

Comment: Please [edit] and show a [mcve].

Comment: ** Following was the run time error **:  Line 431: Char 55: runtime error: pointer index expression with base 0xbebebebebebebebe overflowed to 0x7d7d7d7d7d7d7d7c (basic_string.h)

Comment: @VikramKeswani you need to show a [MCVE].

Comment: @Jabberwocky I have shared the link of problem If you run that code it will run.

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Where is `main`? Where are your `#include`s?

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/largest-number/ I was solving the leetcode problem there was no main function provided . @Jabberwocky

Comment: OK I understand, debugging like this is very painful. Use a debugger on your own computer if you really want to learn C++.

Comment: The comparator for `std::sort` must return false when the values are equal otherwise you have undefined behaviour

Comment: not the problem, but `(s1[i]-'0')==(s2[i]-'0')` is the same as `s1[i]==s2[i]` and same for `<`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a very interesting bug! I have not tested whether this is a leetcode specific issue, but running this code with `sort()` on leetcode, we get the following error:

```
Line 431: Char 55: runtime error: pointer index expression with base 0xbebebebebebebebe overflowed to 0x7d7d7d7d7d7d7d7c (basic_string.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/bits/basic_string.h:440:55
```

which seems to suggest that we're running out of memory for some reason. The fact that this code works with `stable_sort()` but not `sort()` suggests that this might have something to do with the fact that "stable_sort preserves the relative order of the elements with equivalent values" (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/stable_sort/).

The line of code where this is relevant is here

```
if(flag==true && s1.length()==s2.length())
{
    return s1==s2;
}
```

And indeed if we change this to

```
if(flag==true && s1.length()==s2.length())
{
    return s1!=s2;
}
```

which doesn't affect the results, because if, at this point, `flag == true` and both strings have the same length, then they are both equivalent, and swapping string positions does not affect the outcome.

**BUT** we bypass the error. @Vikram Keswani I hope this solves your issue. Personally I would also just replace the code in the `comp()` function with `return s1 > s2;` which should provide the same behaviour as the code that you have.

p.s. I shall leave the pieces of the puzzle here, but if someone more experienced (or when I find more time) would like to investigate this mysterious memory issue further, that'd be great.

Incidentally, the minimum length input required to reproduce this error on leetcode is `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]` which is 17 0's (a strange number).

Comment: Yes, this is the answer. `std::sort` requires the comparator to fulfill certain [requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare). Specifically it must be a strictly weak ordering, and must fulfill `comp(a,a)==false`. In other words, an element _must_ not compare true with itself. OP's function does not fulfill this (`comp("0", "0")` returns true). Your fix flips this and makes the comparator compliant with the requirements.